# Is the Horizon Testnet Currently down?

Tags: horizon, testnet, network, stellar-website

Is the testnet currently functional? Is there an official status website or organisation that issues announcements related to the status of the testnet regarding downtimes, resets or outages?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can read balances and transactions against testNet, but not write. No new transactions and no new accounts.

Comment: Thanks. I now notice that the main public net is also down. I can't even read from the main net on sites like stellarchain.io , steexp.com, or stellar.expert. Very worrying.

Comment: It would be nice if Testnet had a health status page  https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2710/is-therre-a-health-status-page-for-testnet

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a moment in time that has long passed.