# Is there a health status page for testnet?

Tags: testnet

I know testnet is not supposed to be reliable, but it is useful for 
running test suites, as well as conducting usability tests with real users.

I've been getting many 504 Timeouts on the testnet instance lately.

I know I could run my own testnet instance, but having a public testnet improves the developer experience a lot.

If there was a status page for testnet, I would have an easy way to know that it is not a bug in my code causing the error.

I suspect that the timeouts are a testnet problem, because a test suite that has been very stable is now failing with Timeout on transactions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to monitor activity on the testnet is by keeping an eye on the Horizon fee stats endpoint (https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/fee_stats) and adjust fees accordingly.

Earlier today the testnet was seeing a lot of activity causing surge pricing for fees to kick in (this was also affecting Friendbot at the time).

You can also visit the Stellar Dashboard (https://dashboard.stellar.org/) and at the bottom of the page there is a testnet monitor.